# Squid run as root (to use it on 80 port)

Tags: root, squid

I have Ubuntu 16.04 and Squid. It is now configured to run on port 8080 and everything works fine. But I want it to listen on port 80. AFAIK to use port lower than 1024, it has to be run as root.

So how to run it as root? I use `service squid start` command to run it, and have no idea how to make it run as root.

Comment: Doesn't squid already start as root and then drop privileges?

Comment: I sure would hope so :-P

Answer (score 1):

It is not recommended to run squid on port 80. See http://docs.huihoo.com/gnu_linux/squid/html/x505.html for instance in why.

On Ubuntu I would expect you to do this by binding the socket and not by altering permissions or iptables  ...

```
sudo apt-get install libcap2-bin 
sudo setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' /path/to/squid
```

See `man capabilities` and ....

```
CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE
Bind  a  socket  to  Internet domain privileged ports (port numbers less than 1024).
```